# How to add Javascript to simple_form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm using simple_form with Rails 3.2.5.  I have a form that looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }, :html => {:name => "new_user"}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :field_one,
                :placeholder => '30000',
            :autofocus => true,
            :required => true,
            :html => {:onFocus => 'startCalc();'},
            :html => {:onBlur => 'stopCalc();'} %>
# More form fields

<% end %>
```

I'm trying to call a Javascript driven calculation when a user enters a number in the form field, but the Javascript isn't showing up in the outputted HMTL:

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" class="numeric decimal required" id="field_one" name="user[field_one]" placeholder="30000" step="any" type="number" />
```

Does anyone know how to get simple_form to add these bits of Javascript?

Thanks!

Greg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see my error now.  As per the [simple_form documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), I need to use:

```
:input_html => {:onFocus => 'startCalc();'},
:input_html => {:onBlur => 'stopCalc();'}
```

This works!